# Water physics for continuous fall

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, estimation, flow

I would like to know if there is a standard formula to calculate how much volume of water is needed per area unit in order to get a continuous/uninterrupted water flow.

What I would like to achieve is water being pumped to the top of a waterfall-like surface from where the water should fall as a single "curtain" of water instead of being able to see different bodies of water.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any such formula, but I can try to derive an expression for the problem at hand.

For simplicity, let's take a faucet with a rectangular opening of area 1 centimeter squared. Say the drain the water goes to(or anywhere where the falling water stops) is located a distance *l* from the opening of the faucet. Since you mentioned 'curtain', let the falling water have a certain width *w* corresponding to the width of the opening of the faucet. Also, lets consider a small thickness *dx*, corresponding to the length of the opening of the faucet.

When a drop of water is dropped from the faucet, it will take $$t = \sqrt\frac{2l}{g}$$ seconds to hit the drain. So a 'slab' of water of volume $V = (l)(w)(dx)$ will take t seconds to reach the drain. So after one slab leaves the faucet, another has to start in order to get continuous flow. Therefore two slabs have an interval of t seconds between them.

Now, another factor to consider is the time for which the faucet is running. Lets call it *T*. Therefore, the total volume to get continuous water flow for T seconds is $$V_t = \frac{VT}{t}$$

I have oversimplified a lot of things in this answer, but I think this should serve well as an expression in the above mentioned case. Therefore $V_t$ gives the total volume required, given you run it for T seconds. Now, you just have to find a pump.
*You can also expand the above equation accordingly.*